# Material design checkbox change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, material-design

I am trying to dynamically set the checkbox state checked to false/true.
What I have so far is this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bookmakers.length; i++) {
    $('#' + bookmakers[i].id + '-checkbox').prop('checked', filters['bookmakers'][bookmakers[i].id]).change();
    console.log($('#' + bookmakers[i].id + '-checkbox'));
}
```

When I get log from the console, some of the checkboxes are checked: true and some checked: false. The problem is that visually I see all the checkboxes checked. We are using material design, here is some example of the checkbox creation:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bookmakers.length; i++) {
    $bookmakers.append('<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect"><input id="' + bookmakers[i].id + '-checkbox" type="checkbox" class="mdl-switch__input" checked><span class="mdl-switch__label">' + bookmakers[i].name + '</span></label>');
}
```

and then I do this:

```
if(typeof componentHandler != 'undefined')
    componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

to update view. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of solving that problem. One I've used is this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < bookmakers.length; i++) {
    setCheckboxValue($('#' + bookmakers[i].id + '-checkbox'), filters['bookmakers'][bookmakers[i].id]);
}
```

and then `setCheckboxValue` function looks like this:

```
function setCheckboxValue($el, value) {
    var $parent = $el.prop('checked', value).parent();
    removeOrAddClass($parent, 'is-checked', value);
}
```

This is not the cleanest possible way to solve this problem. You can find a `MaterialCheckbox` object in `$el.get(0)` DOM Element and use it's `check` and `uncheck` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers do not allow id´s starting with a number. Especially CSS does not allow selectors starting with a number. Try to change #1-checkbox to #checkbox-1

Comment: but bookmakers[i].id isn't a number, it's string

Comment: what does the filter array contain?
filters['bookmakers'][bookmakers[i].id]

Comment: filters contain each bookmaker if the checkbox with this bookmaker is checked or unchecked {true/false}

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should write a JSfiddle so we can see and test your code. In the meantime, have you tried setting the checkbox state with Javascript?

```
document.getElementById('yourElemID').checked = true; // or false
```

Comment: I solved it by changing the parent's class as is-checked - or none.

Comment: You should update your own answer then, so that others with a similar problems can find it easier. Glad you found a way.